# Make dots active on Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I have this Slider example created with pure JS.

The slider is working great. The only thing left to do would be to activate the three dots so when the 1st slide opens, 1st dot activates, showing different color than the other dots, and so on. Also, you should be able to open the correct slide when clicking dots, so 1st dot opens 1st slide, 2nd dot 2nd slide, and so on.

Could you help me to achieve this? You can find the source code below.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.images');
const offers = document.getElementById('offers');
const link = document.getElementById('links');

let colors = ['#7f86ff', '#2932d1', '#00067f'];
let currentSlide = 0;

let texts = ['Change1', 'Change2', 'Change3'];
let currentText = 0;

let links = ['<a href="https:www.google.com">Link1</a>', '<a href="https:www.is.fi">Link2</a>', '<a href="https:www.betsson.com">Link3</a>'];
let currentLink = 0;

function updateSlide(direction) {
  currentSlide =
    (colors.length + currentSlide + direction)
  % colors.length;
  container.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentSlide];
  container.animate([{opacity:'0.1'}, {opacity:'1.0'}],
  {duration: 200, fill:'forwards'})
}

function updateText(direction) {
  currentText =
    (texts.length + currentText + direction)
  % texts.length;
  offers.innerHTML = texts[currentText];
  offers.animate([{transform:'translateY(-50px)', opacity:'0.0'}, {transform:'translateY(0)', opacity:'1.0'}],
  {duration: 200, fill:'forwards'})
}

function updateLink(direction) {
  currentLink =
    (links.length + currentLink + direction)
  % links.length;
  link.innerHTML = links[currentLink];
  link.animate([{transform:'scale(0,0)'}, {transform:'scale(1.1)'}],
  {duration: 200, fill:'forwards'})
}

updateSlide(0);
updateText(0);
updateLink(0);

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

function nextSlide() {
  updateSlide(+1);
  updateText(+1);
  updateLink(+1);
  clearInterval(myInterval);
}

function prevSlide() {
  updateSlide(-1);
  updateText(-1);
  updateLink(-1);
  clearInterval();
  clearInterval(myInterval);
}

var myInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
  updateSlide(+1),updateText(+1),updateLink(+1);  }, 
  8000);
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.images {
  background-color: #4047c9;
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  min-height: 70vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

#links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#links:hover {
  background-color: #000238;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dots {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#dot1, #dot2, #dot3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(147, 151, 249);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dot1:active, #dot2:active, #dot3:active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prevBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.nextBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="images">
    <button type="button" class="btn prevBtn">Prev Btn</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn nextBtn">Next Btn</button>
    <h1 id="offers">Changing text</h1>
    <a href="#" id="links">Links</a>
    <div class="dots">
    <span id="dot1"></span>
    <span id="dot2"></span>
    <span id="dot3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, according to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

> The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user.

So if you want your dots to be active, you’ll have to write a different way of giving them an active state since they are currently `<span>` tags, I would recommend giving them a class of `.active`, and adding in Javascript code to add that class on to them, or adding in that style programmatically within the Javascript function.

Based on your other request though, you will most likely also have to make the dots an `<a>` tag or something along those lines so you can add functionality on to them to let clicking on the dots bring you to any slide. Something probably along the lines of:

```
function dot1Click() {
  updateSlide(1);
  updateText(1);
  updateLink(1);
  dot1.style.backgroundColor = #fff;
}
```

Then you should have something along the lines of what you want. I'll return to this question when I have more time to iron out a code snippet, but I wanted to give you something to help you get started!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this out.